# Execute .c file to generate .exe from c# Form Application

Tags: c#, c, gcc

I'm trying to use gcc compiler to get Output exe file. When I perform this from file explorer and cmd manually it work as expected but through Code no output is generated. I'm new to this C# and any help would be really appreciated.

```
Process process = new Process()      
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
                process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Users\abc\Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\CodeJam_FormApplication\CodeJam_FormApplication";
                startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
                startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
                startInfo.Arguments = "/C gcc Test.c -o Output.exe";
                process.StartInfo = startInfo;
                process.Start();
```

Comment: I suggest not hiding the cmd window to see what the output is, there's maybe an error message that will help you figure out what is going wrong.

Comment: Are you setting your working directory in line 3 and then overwrite this change in line 7 with the newly created ProcessStartInfo where you did not set a working directory?